# Joomla 3.10.1 Pre Update Check Missing

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, upgrade

I upgraded a few of my sites from 3.9.28 to 3.10.1 today. I can't see any pre-upgrade check as described here https://docs.joomla.org/Pre-Update_Check

I've cleared the site cache, refreshed the page multiple times and clicked `check for updates`. No errors in the browser console.

When I go to components > Joomla update I can see the following message on the `live update` tab;

> You already have the latest Joomla version, 3.10.1.

The `upload & update` tab displays a blue info message;

> You can use this feature to update Joomla if your server is behind a
> firewall or otherwise unable to contact the update servers. First
> download the Joomla Upgrade Package in ZIP format from the official
> Joomla download page. Then use the fields below to upload and install
> it.

Am I missing something? Do I need to change the update settings? Couldn't see any information in the docs about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the Joomla Update page select Options up in the top right corner.

[image]

From there change the channel to Joomla Next, you are probably still on Default which is Joomla 3.x
[image]

You may also have to go into Extensions->Manage->Update and Clear Cache and Find Updates after switching between the Default and Joomla Next channels.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Irata - is this documented anywhere? Seems like it should be

Comment: It is documented here, https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Components_Joomla_Update_Configuration but the bit about refreshing cache just comes from my own trial and error last week.